# JavaScript: Shorthand to toggle a non-boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

Is there a better shorthand to toggle `foo`?

```
type Foo = 'BAR' | 'BAZ';

let foo: Foo = 'BAR';

const toggleFoo = () => {
  foo = foo === 'BAR' ? 'BAZ' : foo;
};

toggleFoo();
```

Comment: Let me ask it this way, why do you use two magic strings to mimic a boolean? Ain't toggling a boolean simpler? Or dealing with a boolean in general

Comment: Boolean won't be feasible as `foo`  is actually a value that needs to be used. ON and OFF are just dummy values for sake of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take an object with the opposite as value.

```
const toggleFoo = () => {
  foo = { BAR: 'BAZ', BAZ: 'BAR' }[foo];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With only two states, it can be simpler to use `0` to represent "off" and `1` to represent "on". This has the added advantage of being simple to use in an `if`-statement.

```
let foo = 1;
const toggleFoo = () => foo ^= 1;
if(foo){
   //on
} else {
  //off
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea if you want a reusable way of toggling between two states.

```
const createToggler = <F, T>(toggleStates: [F, T], initialState = false) => {
  let state = initialState
  return () => {
    state = !state
    return toggleStates[+state] // convert boolean to number for indexing
  }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAVEBzLAbR8MAvDADwBiANDOgHwAUU2eiAylKohAFwwDaVGgF1qASzCioo5LnadiMAGYyIiAJTFaMAN4AoGDHyxo8kuMnTZHNPphIoAV3hgY9DUS16DBk2gUBCX0RbA3snFyYcfDk0CD4AaiChGAB6FLhwADcCWAAjEBB8ZAiQGDAHAFtcgiUQQnEAE0QAD3EsWwBfXS7dUEg8gtxMKJqSBBQ0YZZ4ej5lXFVqKHgHRCE1XV7wCELEADpcbHp8wqn8GbUNNJhl1a3IXYOjk6Hmc7cr9PnVe538J6wx0GZwIH1S6VuwV%20xmWbRBhDGSE48NmAHIAPLkcio6gYgByqJENxW6k2fT%20%200OgOg8Dhb1Bl3BMEx5F%20jyp9BpdJGF0%20zLxbP%20HK5YCwKMZ1xZZO2sAqomaiAa8IU42R9JmfG0MAADvAQNreKiABaIXCHVEwDq4gDudVwDUJSxJG0FlKOcoVSvVbj2uv1fONpvNroB9A9ivFAdt8HtqKAA)

(Not sure if there's any way of avoiding a runtime typecheck of the return value, though, in case it's a non primitive such as my `mixedToggler` example.)

Answer (score 0):

Merging some of the answers I came to this approach:

```
enum StateValues {
  OFF = 0,
  ON = 1
}

type State = StateValues.OFF | StateValues.ON;

const toggleState = (state: State) => {
  return state ^= 1
}

let myState: State = StateValues.OFF;

console.log(StateValues[myState]); // "OFF"

myState = toggleState(myState);
console.log(StateValues[myState]); // "ON"

myState = toggleState(myState);
console.log(StateValues[myState]); // "OFF"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzsAaggNmYBnKBvAKCigHkAxMqAXigAYAaI0gOWqgEYCBfAguATwAOwWImRt4SVBizYAdOUoAfUVLSYcC5gG5eAYwD2IbHChwDAcwvpgk8TQAUJqQC5VyAJTUAfPiYAnYDgwfxAoZ3EAPRpOHgIbUwh%20O2A3FIkxaQ15RV0CQ2MDGzl0SwcU9VkAbSSUgF0PPNrMtnMrGxSHZqlG-KNsIuASsoqZHBrkzIamyalWy2tbTK7Zz10CgeLSi3LMyvHu5GmCIA)